# How can I access all of my google spreadsheet ID's?

Tags: c#, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm fairly new to coding and c#. I'm building an app that accesses google spreadsheets via an API, I turn this data into XML, zip it and write it to a stream. It works fine, but instead of adding every spreadsheet ID manually to my list I want to make another API call that will retrieve every ID in my google sheets account so that I can store them to a list and update it every time I run the app.

I'm banging my head off a wall looking for answers but I think this is not available via a sheets API but maybe through the drive API??, any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm not looking for anyone to write my code, but please point me in the right direction, or am I trying to do something that cannot be done?

```
public class GoogleSheetsReader
{

  private string apiKey;
  public Stream OutStream { get; set; }
  List<string> SpreadSheetIdList { get; set; }

  public GoogleSheetsReader(string apiKey)
  {
     this.apiKey = apiKey;

  }

  public Stream Main()
  {
     SheetsService sheetsService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
     {
        HttpClientInitializer = GetCredential(),
        ApplicationName = "My Project To XML",
        ApiKey = apiKey,
     });


     using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
     {
        using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(memory, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
           SpreadSheetIdList = new List<string>(); // not the best place for the list, just testing funtionality
           SpreadSheetIdList.Add("1oZlfj6XZOrPs9Qti9K9iKL6itZChM8dlwwJFSvBNzUc");
           SpreadSheetIdList.Add("1oU3sjd7QoOgQ2PvmC7NxciyM1MRXns6-Z9vMayFgOjU");

           foreach (var spreadSheetId in SpreadSheetIdList)
           {
              var ssRequest = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadSheetId);
              Data.Spreadsheet service = ssRequest.Execute();

              foreach (var sheet in service.Sheets)
              {
                 var sheetName = sheet.Properties.Title;
                 SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadSheetId, sheetName);

                 SpreadsheetsResource.GetRequest requestForSpreadSheet = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadSheetId);
                 requestForSpreadSheet.Ranges = sheetName;

                 Data.Spreadsheet response1 = requestForSpreadSheet.Execute();
                 var spreadSheetName = response1.Properties.Title;

                 Data.ValueRange response = request.Execute();
                 ZipArchiveEntry entry = zip.CreateEntry($"{spreadSheetName}\\{sheetName}.xml");

                 using (Stream ZipFile = entry.Open())
                 {
                    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SchemaMaker(response)); // SchemaMaker converts my sheet data to required xml format
                    ZipFile.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                 }
              }
           }
        }
        OutStream = new MemoryStream(memory.ToArray());
     }
     return OutStream;
  }

  public string SchemaMaker(ValueRange _param)
  {
     var result = "<TABLE>";
     var headers = _param.Values[0];

     for (int i = 1; i < _param.Values.Count; i++)
     {
        result = result + "<ROW>";
        for (int j = 0; j < _param.Values[i].Count; j++)
        {
           result = result + $"<{headers[j]}>{_param.Values[i][j]}</{headers[j]}>";
        }
        result = result + "</ROW>";
     }
     result = result + "</TABLE>";

     var element = XElement.Parse(result);
     var settings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
     settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
     settings.Indent = true;
     settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
     var xmlFormat = element.ToString();

     return xmlFormat;
  }

  public static UserCredential GetCredential()
  {
     string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
     return null;
  }
 }
```

Comment: It looks like the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters) is the way to go here, also see the `file.list` [operator example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters#examples_for_fileslist).

Comment: This looks promising, Thanks Chris.